# Spark 3.1.2 NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateFunction.toAggregateExpression$default$2()Lscala/Option;

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm Building a jar and running it in EMR cluster.

I'm using spark-alchemy below version and calling a function named ***hll_init_agg*** inside **.agg** and getting above error.

CODE where it's called:

```
Dataset<Row> groupByDf = df
                        .groupBy(functions.col("A"), functions.col("DAY"), functions.col("C"), functions.col("D"))
                    .agg(com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.functions.hll_init_agg(functions.col("ID"), 0.005, "AGKN").alias("NEWID"));
```

> ```
> <dependency>
>                <groupId>com.swoop</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>spark-alchemy_2.12</artifactId>
>                 <version>1.1.0</version>
>             </dependency>
> ```

Stack Trace :

> 22/03/23 07:06:22 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateFunction.toAggregateExpression$default$2()Lscala/Option;
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.AggregateFunction.toAggregateExpression$default$2()Lscala/Option;
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.WithHelper.withAggregateFunction(WithHelper.scala:13)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.WithHelper.withAggregateFunction$(WithHelper.scala:10)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.functions$.withAggregateFunction(HLLFunctions.scala:653)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.HLLFunctions.hll_init_agg(HLLFunctions.scala:695)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.HLLFunctions.hll_init_agg$(HLLFunctions.scala:695)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.functions$.hll_init_agg(HLLFunctions.scala:653)
> at
> com.swoop.alchemy.spark.expressions.hll.functions.hll_init_agg(HLLFunctions.scala)
> at
> com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx(xxxx.java:103)
> at com.xxx.xxx.xxxxx(MainClass.java:315)    at
> com.xxxx.xxxx.main(MainClass.java:104)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:728)
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
> Application application_1647925696500_0096 finished with failed status
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1196)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1587)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:936)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1015)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1024)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 22/03/23 10:06:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
> 22/03/23 10:06:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
> /tmp/spark-a055b36c-0f9a-46f0-9575-893d300705f8 22/03/23 10:06:14 INFO
> ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
> /tmp/spark-9d482629-a936-4c16-8df4-ac426dcc12ff

Is there any heads up on this to resolve the issue.
Any suggestion is much appreciated .

Comment: yes, use functions that exists

Comment: hll_init_agg this function is already exist and same one i'm using, but even though it's not working .

Comment: check your dependency tree, maybe you have different version loaded from somewhere but in general it will be hard to find an error without any code and error which looks like it was posted here shorter than it was in console

Comment: I've added the code. Also maven dependency has only below details for alchemy :

[INFO] +- com.swoop:spark-alchemy_2.12:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.agkn:hll:jar:sources:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:6.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.agkn:hll:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:6.5.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

Resolved the issue. There was a jar version mismatch. EMR Cluster spark was having  jar `spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.1-amzn-0.jar` but we have added this jar in our maven dependency `spark-catalyst_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-0.jar`

Upon updating the version of jar to 3.1.2 , I was able to run the job.